# wrapping text in RTL language using LWUIT

Tags: netbeans, java-me, word-wrap, right-to-left, lwuit

I'm developing a [j2me](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/J2ME-Java-2-Platform-Micro-Edition) application using [Netbeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/projects/www/) and [LWUIT](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lwuit-intro-138622.html) library. I'm using Persian (RTL) language in my application using localization and showing them with bitmap font.

In order to wrap multiple line texts in a `Form` as `Label`s or in `TextAreas`. My problem is that they are breaking to multiple lines when they reach to the middle of screen width i.e they don’t fill one line till the end of the screen width and go to the next line. I set

```
maxwidth=Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());
```

Would you help me with this issue?

Comment: He means, you have to click the check mark that appears to the left of an answer when that answer has helped you the most. یعنی توی سوالهای قبلی و جدیدت جواب نهاییو که گرفتی کنارش اون تیک سبز رو بزن.

Comment: they havent helped me yet , thanks for ur concern :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the text area set the columns number to a large value (100 or so).

Answer (score 2):

try using `YourComponent.setPreferredW(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());`

Comment: tanx frayab , i will check it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages like Hindi(India) where unicodes are used even though they are LTR , for that we can do TextArea.setUseStringWidth(true); 
This will wrap the text according to the font glyphs of that language.